# LINQ not checking for null

Tags: c#, linq

The following code is supposed to take a simple average of Tuition rates if present for each row, but the requirement dictates the imported data set allow null values.

The line below is not properly checking value and I am getting the error: "ArgumentNullException was unhandled by user code, Value cannot be null."

```
TUITIONCurr = g
    .Where(p => !object.Equals(p.Field<double>("TUITION"),null))
    .DefaultIfEmpty()
    .Average(p => p.Field<double>("TUITION")),
```

Comment: Do you need to remove `null` (or actually `DBNull.Value`) values, or substitute them with zeroes?

Answer (score 2):

You should be comparing to `DBNull.Value`, not `null`:

```
TUITIONCurr = g
    .Where(p => !object.Equals(p.Field<double>("TUITION"), DBNull.Value))
    .Average(p => p.Field<double>("TUITION"));
```

Once you've filtered out nulls, you don't need the `DefaultIfEmpty()` call.

Comment: `TUITIONCurr = g.Where(p => !object.Equals(p.Field<double>("TUITION"), DBNull.Value)).DefaultIfEmpty().Average(p => p.Field<double>("TUITION"))`  returns the same original error

Comment: In that case, it means one of the `p`'s is actually `null`; not sure why that would be, but you should assign `g.ToList()` to a variable and inspect it in the debugger to see what's actually in the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the `DataRow.Field` method, try using [`DataRow.IsNull`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3fwatee0%28v=VS.90%29.aspx). Also, you don't need the call to `DefaultIfEmpty()`.

E.g.:

```
TUITIONCurr = g
   .Where(p => !p.IsNull("TUITION"))
   .Average(p => p.Field<double>("TUITION")),
```

Comment: Downvoter -- care to explain why? If my answer is technically incorrect, I would like to be made aware.